# encoding issues with rvest, "Â " appearing instead of a space in character strings

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table from baseball-reference.com using rvest. my code is:

```
url="http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/NL/2016-standard-batting.shtml"
css=""#players_standard_batting.sortable.stats_table"
read_html(url) %>% html_node(css) %>% html_table()->nlbatting.raw
```

At this point the table is a bit garbled, there is an 'Â' wherever there should be a space. I have tried

```
nlbatting.raw %>% mutate(Name=repair_encoding(Name))->nlbatting.raw
```

which makes everything look ok, but then I get really odd behavior. For instance:

```
 nlbatting.raw$Name[86]=="Yoenis Cespedes"
 FALSE
```

and:

```
 gsub(" ","_",nlbatting.raw$Name[86])
 "Yoenis Cespedes"
```

I have tried different encoding parameters in `read_html()` but nothing changes. I tried leaving the encoding alone and just gsubbing out the 'Â' but have the same problem. Any help would be great, thanks in advance!
ps. Long time lurker first time poster, sorry if I've missed something obvious

Answer (score 0):

Edited to fix html nodes (from ".class" to ".stats_table"). It worked fine for me. Try this again:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/NL/2016-standard-batting.shtml"
data <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(".stats_table") %>% html_table()
head(data[[1]])
head(data[[2]])
```

Comment: thanks, but that's just giving me an empty list. Did that actually work for you?

Comment: edited above to fix how I specified css class (should have been ".stats_table" not basic ".table".

Comment: Thanks again! it's the correct data with that css selector but I'm still getting :"Â " whenever there should be a space in a character string. I wonder if it's something local. I'm on 64 bit windows 10, what operating system do you use?